# Is there a reason so many MW3 questions have the call-of-duty tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems half the questions specific to MW3 are tagged with both the [modern-warfare-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-warfare-3) tag and the [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) series tag. Is there any reason we should not go to town on them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Release the kraken upon any badly tagged question you find!**

Usually we are pretty good about fixing tags, but MW3 vs Skyrim was a hectic time.  If the question is only about MW3, the [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) tag has no business there.

Be aware that editing a massive number of questions at once will flood the front page with them!  Don't go overboard.

Comment: Oops, didn't think retags moved questions to the top.

Comment: I think it is less of an issue at a slow time of the day.  I wouldn't spam the tag edits during prime time, though I can't tell you exactly when that is. :)

Comment: Also, the [tag:call-of-duty] tag is actually for the first game in the series.  Questions about the series as a whole should use [tag:call-of-duty-series]